# Use setInterval without increasing memory consuming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: s]

I use `setInterval` in my code to make my slider work. It should change image each 5 second . But I see that when I use it , it consume new memory all the time . How can I use `setInterval` without consuming new memory ?

```
const Slider = ({ children, sliderIndex, setSlideIndex }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  useInterval(() => {
    setSlideIndex((sliderIndex + 1) % children.length)
  }, 5000)

  const animateFunc = useCallback(
    (child, indx) => {
      return (
        (indx === sliderIndex && (
          <div className={classes.root} key={indx}>
            {children[sliderIndex].image}
          </div>
        )) ||
        null
      )
    },
    [children, classes.root, sliderIndex]
  )

  return children.map(animateFunc)
}
```

i use @use-it/interval hook for it https://www.npmjs.com/package/@use-it/interval

Comment: First thing, why you think the bottle neck comes from interval? Second thing, Im pretty sure the issue is with how you handle the renders, `children.map(animateFunc)` is NOT how you map children in React (see React docs Children API). You should add codesandbox for more help...

Comment: Another small advice, you import a npm package with so many dependencies for just calling an interval? https://github.com/donavon/use-interval/blob/master/src/index.js, better to inline this code

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely to me that the interval is actually causing your issue here.

Below is a snippit that will run for two minutes - printing a new line to the console each second. Take a look at the memory usage over time in this page - it won't grow. You can even add a heavy for/while function into it if you like. I think your issue is elsewhere in your code and there are some good comments above to follow up.

```js
let n = 1;
let myInterval = setInterval(function(){ console.log("hello number:" + n++); shouldIStop(120) }, 1000);

function shouldIStop(maxCount){
  if (n >= maxCount){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
```